# 802.1x Wired Setting for PEAP and TLS Authentication

Tags: security, authentication, openssl

I am new to ubuntu. I recently set up a Freeradius in ubuntu and connected successfully with the supplicant's PC using MD5.
I am using ethernet cable to connect these three items: two Ubuntu PC and one cisco switch.
I would like to try other Authentication method (PEAP and TLS).
My question is: How to create the certificate/key/anyfile with "openssl" command?
And how to do with the wired setting for the supplicant's PC in order to use PEAP and TLS authentication?

Below is my set up information:

**Authentication Server**

1. Ubuntu version: 20.04.2 LTS
2. Freeradius version: 3.0.20
3. Fixed IP Address: 192.168.100.22
4. File configuration:

4a) user==>

raduser Cleartext-Password := "dfgh"

4b) clients.conf==>

client 192.168.100.33 {

secret = erty

shortname = ciscoswitch

}

**Authenticator**

1. Cisco Switch: SG250-08HP
2. IP Address: 192.168.100.33
3. Setting:

3a) Radius Client==> IP Address: 192.168.100.22 / Key String: erty / Authentication Port: 1812

3b) 802.1X Authentication==> Properties==> Port-Based Authentication: Enable / Authentication Method: RADIUS

==> Port Authentication==> Port(GE1)==> Port Control: Forced Authorized *(Authentication Server)*                                                   
==> Port(GE2)==> Port Control: Auto *(Supplicant's PC)*

**Supplicant**

1. Ubuntu version: 20.04.2 LTS
2. Freeradius version: 3.0.20
3. Fixed IP Address: 192.168.100.55

3a) Scenario 1 - *How?*

802.1x Security: Enabled

Authentication: Protected EAP

Anonymous identity:

CA certificate:

PEAP version:

Inner authentication:

Username:

Password:

3b) Scenario 2 - *How?*

802.1x Security: Enabled

Authentication: TLS

Identity:

User certificate:

CA certificate:

Private key:

Private key password: